# AngularJS : directive inner ng-repeat, dynamically add model item, get undefined attributes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have my directive inner ng-repeat and it works in initial load, but when I dynamically add modelItem then I'm getting undefined values for attributes of my directive.

```
<li ng-repeat="item in item_list track by $index">
   <count-down-timer id="item.id" nowdate="item.nowdate" enddate="item.duedate"></count-down-timer>
</li>


.directive('countDownTimer',['$http', function($http) {
  return {
    restrict: 'AEC',    
    template: "<div class='float-left googlefont font-32'></div>",
    replace: true,
    scope: { id: '=' , nowdate: '=', enddate: '='},  
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {     
      var slct = "#c"+scope.id;
      var slct2= "c"+scope.id;
      element.attr("id", slct2);
      $(slct).coconut({ //coconut jquery plugin, settingsCode});               
    }
  };
}]);
```

I also try to solve that with $watch eg:

```
scope.$watch('enddate', function(edate) {
    console.log("end date observe before: " + edate);
        scope.edate = edate;        
});
```

but whenever I add single item, this code print enddates of all items in item_list(not as expected only one single added item).

Comment: Are you getting undefined for scope.id, scope.nowdate and scope.enddate?

Comment: I'm getting undefined for all attributes(scope.id, scope.nowdate, scope.enddate)

Comment: How are you adding a new item?

Comment: after ng-click="addItem()" I'm calling controller's addItem() { $scope.item_list.unshift({itembody..}); }

Comment: Try removing `track by $index`

Comment: Inside this watch you can add comparsion of new and old value. `scope.$watch('enddate', function(newVal,oldVal) {
if(newVal!==oldVal){
    console.log("end date observe before: " + newVal);
        scope.edate = newVal; }       
});`

Comment: removing track by $index  works, thanks :)